# Need to match a string containing the string file: and report in the string

Tags: c++11

Need to match a string containing the string "file://\\" and "report" in the string.

if i use the regular expression (file://\\\\)(.*)\\\\report\\\\(.*) it is working fine.

but, if i use the expression (file://\\\\)(.*)\\report\\(.*) it is giving errors.

My question is why do need to use four back slashes(\\\\) to do a match for one back slash present before and after the report string.

```
*wstring target(L"file://\\\\Example\\report\\001");
wsmatch wideMatch;
wregex wrx(L"(file://\\\\)(.*)\\\\report\\\\(.*)");

if (regex_match(target.cbegin(), target.cend(), wideMatch, wrx))
    wcout << L"The matching text is:" << wideMatch.str() << endl;*
```

can some one please answer. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Isn't \ specially treated? So \t mean tabulator \n new line and \\ means single \ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are special in both string literals and in regular expressions. To match a backslash in a regular expression you need to escape it, by adding a second backslash. And to have two backslashes in a string literal then you need to escape both of them leading to you needing four backslashes.